# Splitting input string into a function to search text file

Tags: python, search, text, io, delimiter

I've gotten plenty of help so far on this site I'm very new to Python programming and stackoverflow it self.

So currently I have a program that will prompt the user for a keyword/string to search through a text document and print out the resulting data in between that keyword. However, my goal is the follow:

- Allow the user to input many keywords into one input prompt (The keyword will be separated by a delimiter such as ,;' ./ etc.
- Then the program will search for these keyword and print whats in between, We'll call this data in between the **Important Data**
- Then it will print out this **Important Data** to a new text file for the user to read.

My issue is currently the first part where to pass these multiple inputs into a function that searches.

### Current Code:

This is an example of my current code:

```
def process(infile, outfile, keywords):

    keys = [ [k[0], k[1], 0] for k in keywords ]
    endk = None
    with open(infile, "rb") as fdin:
        with open(outfile, "wb") as fdout:
            for line in fdin:
                if endk is not None:
                    fdout.write(line)
                    if line.find(endk) >= 0:
                        fdout.write("\n")
                        endk = None
                else:
                    for k in keys:
                        index = line.find(k[0])
                        if index >= 0:
                            fdout.write(line[index + len(k[0]):].lstrip())
                            endk = k[1]
                            k[2] += 1
    if endk is not None:
        raise Exception(endk + " not found before end of file")
    return keys



from Tkinter import *
import tkSimpleDialog
import tkMessageBox
from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename
import re

root = Tk()
w = Label(root, text ="Configuration Inspector")
w.pack()
tkMessageBox.showinfo("Welcome", "This is version 1.00 of Configuration Inspector ")
infile = askopenfilename() #
outfile = askopenfilename() #

start_token = tkSimpleDialog.askstring("Serial Number", "What is the device serial number?")
end_token = tkSimpleDialog.askstring("End Keyword", "What is the end keyword")
DATA_IN = start_token

Spilt_Start = start_token.split(' ')


process(infile,outfile,((Spilt_Start + ",SHOWALL",end_token),))
```

So this code allows you to pick a file to read from, then a file to write to. After prompting that it will ask you to input a series of input STARTKeywords to search through until it hits the ENDKeyword.

### Goal of the Program:

So an example of this lets say I have this Text Document:

```
unimportant data unimportant data unimportant data unimportant data unimportant data unimportant data unimportant data unimportant data unimportant data unimportant data 
unimportant data unimportant data  **Start Keyword 1** something
data1
data2
data3
data4
data5
** ENDkeyword1 **
unimportant data unimportant data unimportant data unimportant data unimportant data unimportant data unimportant data unimportant data unimportant data unimportant data 
unimportant data unimportant data  **Start Keyword 2** something
data1
data2
data3
data4
data5
Data6
** ENDkeyword2 **
unimportant data unimportant data unimportant data unimportant data unimportant data unimportant data unimportant data unimportant data unimportant data unimportant data 
unimportant data unimportant data  **Start Keyword 3** something
data1
data2
data3
data4
data5
data6
data7
data8
** ENDkeyword3 **
```

So then our output goal is this:

```
something
data1
data2
data3
data4
data5
ENDkeyword1

something
data1
data2
data3
data4
data5
Data6
ENDkeyword2

something
data1
data2
data3
data4
data5
data6
data7
data8
ENDkeyword3
```

### Personal Idea on how to fix this:

This seems to me like a pretty messy input file but I need that data inbetween those Start Keyword and End keyword so I prompt the user to input the keywords that will be Separated and searched for.

> StartKeyword1, StartKeyword2, StartKeyword3

Awesome now im going to prompt the user to input the EndKeyword so the program knows when to Stop writing data and look for the next keyword.

> ENDKeyword1, ENDKeyword2, ENDKeyword3

great so now the program has essentially a list or array of Keywords now I need to pass those keywords through the function that executes the search method.

In this case its the

> def process(infile, outfile, keywords)

keywords has two parameters which are (startkeyword, endkeyword)

So now that I have this how would I able to execute this search function once with each one of these keywords.

Or maybe im just over complicating this simple program :/

**So the end question:**

How do grab an input with multiple delimiters and search through a text document for those split strings/keywords?

Comment: I just scrolled for 3 pages and don't see a single question mark. [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @CoryKramer got a little to ahead of myself, Please see the edit. Essentially i just want to search through a text document with multiple strings and print out the results when each string/keyword is found. I have the function to search setup i just need to figure out how to Split an input string for example `keyword1,keyword2,keyword3` then pass those three or more keywords through the search function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to create a for loop inorder to loop through the multiple inputs in the delimiter.

so for example my input would be

```
start_token = tkSimpleDialog.askstring("Serial Number", "What is the Serial?")
splitInput = start_token.split(' ') #Our Delimiter is space in this case

for inputStrings in splitInput:
   process(infile,outfile,((inputStrings,"end token"),))
```

this way i can have multiple string inputs that are separated by a space or comma then pass those through a function using the loop to loop through the list of input strings.